# redireccting URLs in namecheap

Tags: http-redirect

I would like to redirect a couple of pages to another page in the same website but there is no way to do it under systeme.io.

I have access in namecheap but not sure how to do it.

Example: [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) => [www.example.com/test/](http://www.example.com/test/)

Example: [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) => [www.example.com/test/](http://www.example.com/test/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this webpage will help:
[namecheap.com knowledgebase page](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/385/2237/how-to-redirect-a-url-for-a-domain/)

Answer (score 0):

In order to set the redirect,

you can go to "Domains" tab which would display a list of your registered domains. Then locate the domain which you want to set up a redirect in the list. Once you are on the domain management page, look for options related to URL redirects.

In the URL redirect settings page, choose "Permanent(301)" in the type of redirect > add 'redirect to' URL to 'www.example.com/test/' and save your changes.

Keep in mind that DNS changes, including redirects, may take some time to propagate across the internet. This means that the redirect may not take effect immediately and could take a few hours or more to work consistently.

Give it a go and let me know if that works :D